# PHP to return gethostbyname($lookup) value

Tags: php

I am using the code below (simplified version) to determine if my IPs are on a blacklist. I need to modify it to be able to determine if an IP is on a Whitelist. The function will require me to see a specific code returned.

```
127.0.0.1 
127.0.0.2 
127.0.0.3 
127.0.0.4 
127.0.0.5
```

How can this be adjusted to return the (code) output value when the script runs?

```
$host = '222.22.222.222';
$rbl  = 'hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com';
$rev = array_reverse(explode('.', $host));
$lookup = implode('.', $rev) . '.' . $rbl;
if ($lookup != gethostbyname($lookup)) {

   echo "ip: $host is listed in $rbl\n";
} else {
   echo "ip: $host NOT listed in $rbl\n";
}
```

EDIT:  Sorry guys, The function of the script above will return confirmation if the IP address is on the blacklist entered in $rlb. However, Hostkarma returns a code, one of the 127.0 codes shown above as each code indicates a different block status. I need to get the code. "echo $lookup;" just returns the reverse lookup, like this: 222.222.22.222.hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com

Comment: Can you try to clarify what you want the expected output to be? My best bet what you mean is Michael's answer, but I doubt that's what you really need (just because it's too simple).

Comment: If you're getting the same string returned, that means the lookup failed (see the manual http://ca.php.net/gethostbyname).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$lookup = implode('.', $rev) . '.' . $rbl;
$value = gethostbyname($lookup);
if ($lookup != $value){
   echo "ip: $host is listed in $rbl\n";
   echo "return value: $value\n";
}
else{
   echo "ip: $host NOT listed in $rbl\n";
}
```

The `127.x.x.x` code should be given to you as the value returned by `gethostbyname`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
echo $lookup;
```

Comment: @Michael -- did the OP mean that where??

Comment: @Neal: that was also my best interpretation of the question

Comment: Sorry guys, The function of the script above will return confirmation if the IP address is on the blacklist entered in $rlb. However, Hostkarma returns a code, one of the 127.0 codes shown above as each code indicates a different block status. I need to get the code. "echo $lookup;" just returns the reverse lookup, like this: 222.222.22.222.hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com

Comment: No problem JT. I assumed this wasn't what you needed, but I thought I would give it a go :)

Comment: While doing some testing, it seems that the service won't accept IP addresses, only hostnames. Works fine for me if I use a hostname, for example `ghs.l.google.com.hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com` (mail server for Google Apps)